# Chromium browsers (MSEdge/Chrome) input type="text", dictation software, and cursor position

Tags: html, textbox, user-input, dictation

Given a HTML element , we are experiencing an issue with integration with dictation software, where the user speaks while the focus is in a html textbox.

The problem that is occurring is that while typing, the text is entered into the textbox as expected, but when it reaches the right most boundary of the textbox, the text as input by dictation continues to be entered, but the cursor is not placed at the end of the line, so the reader cannot validate the text they are speaking (and we all know how bad dictation to text can be).

The user is required to stop dictating, and use the mouse to jump to the end of the line to see what was input.  To expound on this, say a textbox accepts 150 characters (with spaces) into the visible area, and then they type another word to extend the text to 160 characters.  We see that 150 characters are still visible, but the cursor does not jump to the 160th (end of line) of the textbox, and is impossible to see the text just entered.

A good way to demonstrate this is to use Windows 11 built in dictation feature by hitting the Windows key and "H" simultaneously, place the mouse cursor into a textbox, and start talking.

This works without issue using the windows feature, but with the 3rd party software, it is not working and presents the issue described above.

Just trying to get my head around the root cause of this issue, and am wondering if anyone has any deeper knowledge on the mechanics of input into a standard HTML textbox?  I have a feeling it may have to do with the mechanism by which the software is introducing text into the textbox.

Thanks in advance.